# Radio button list with IList View Model in C# MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a radio button list with an `IList` View Model in C# MVC 5. My ViewModel values are passed to controller Action Result method.

However, the webpage allows the user to select multiple radio buttons. What I need to how do I select individual button for my list items (one at a time).

Here's the screen for selected radio buttons:

[image: screenshot]

Here's my **ViewModel**:

```cs
public class DeliveryDateVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool SelectedItem { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryDay { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryType { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my **View**:

```html
@model IList<ViewModels.DeliveryDateVM>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)  {
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].Id)
    @{var uniqueID =  Model[i].Id;}

    <tr>
      <td>
        @{var uniqueID =  Model[i].Id;}
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model[i].SelectedItem, true, new { id = uniqueID })
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].DeliveryType)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].DeliveryType)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].DeliveryDay)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].DeliveryDay)
      </td>
    </tr>
  }

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
}
```

The controller values pass screen:

[image: Controller Model Binder]

Here's my **GET Controller**:

```cs
public ActionResult DeliveryDates()
{
  var model = db.DeliveryPeriods
               .Select(c =>
                    new DeliveryDateVM()
                {
                    Id = c.Id,
                    DeliveryDay = c.DeliveryDay,
                    DeliveryType = c.DeliveryType,

                }).ToList();

   return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Radio buttons need to be grouped by name and your giving each radio button a different `name` attribute.

Change you view models to

```
public class MainVM // rename as required
{
  public string SelectedDay { get; set; }
  public List<DeliveryDateVM> Days { get; set; }
}
public class DeliveryDateVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryDay { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryType { get; set; }
}
```

so that you view is

```
@model MainVM 
....
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Days.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedDay, Model.Days[i].DeliveryDay, new { id = "" })

  @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Days[i].DeliveryType)
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Days[i].DeliveryType)
  ....
}
```

This will now generate all radio buttons with `name="SelectedDay"` and the value of `SelectedDay` when you post back to your model will be the value of the `DeliveryDay` (i.e. "Monday" or "Tuesday" etc)

Side note: You may want to consider changing the `DeliveryDay` and `SelectDay` properties to a [DayOfWeek](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx) enum and also create your own enum for `DeliveryType`.

Based on your comments, the revised get method would be

```
MainVM model = new MainVM
{
  SelectedDay = "Monday", // set this if you want a default button selected
  Days = db.DeliveryPeriods.Select(c => new DeliveryDateVM()
  { 
    Id = c.Id, 
    DeliveryDay = c.DeliveryDay, 
    DeliveryType = c.DeliveryType,
  }).ToList()
};
return View(model);
```

Comment: If add this way, The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List. This is my [HttpGet] method
var model = db.DeliveryPeriods
               .Select(c =>
                new MainVM()
                {
                
                }).ToList();

Comment: No. you need initialize a new instance of `MainVM` and then set the `Days` property to a collection. You did not give enough info (I have no idea what `db.DeliveryPeriods` returns and what properties it has. If you add the models to the question and the existing GET method I can update the answer.

Comment: Pls tell me how do I change [HttpGet] method now. It'll come now The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[.ViewModels.MainVM]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'ViewModels.MainVM'.

Comment: This is my get method.   public ActionResult DeliveryDates()
        {
var model = db.DeliveryPeriods
               .Select(c =>
   
             new DeliveryDateVM()
                {
                    Id = c.Id,
                    DeliveryDay = c.DeliveryDay,
                    DeliveryType = c.DeliveryType,
               
                }).ToList();

 return View(model);
        }

Comment: Give me 5 min (you really should edit your question - too difficult to read in comments especially when you do not even format it)

Comment: Note also your POST method will need to be changed to `[HttpPost] public ActionResult DeliveryDates(MainVM model)`